# If-Statement in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet, linked below, with a column for student names and then columns for all subjects with the student marks beneath them.

The students do not all do the same subjects though.

What I would like to do is to capture the subjects and marks which each student does in the same sheet.

So that I had Student name, then Subject 1, subject 2, subject 3 etc. I only want to know the subjects that the student takes. I have created the columns for this information in cells X to AR in my sheet.

I have no idea how to do this. Please help, please...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WfmUEcvFMiw-R_TMrh30jG8gLhCDT-h-dz_PP_sNn4Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A list all in one cell or in separate cells?

Comment: @EmilyAlden Thanks for your reply, I want to populate the cells X to AR in my sheet with the subject information (subject name, subject code, subject mark) for each learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:W8<>"", $E$1:$W$1, ))&","), , 40000)), " ,", ""),","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you @player0 this is close to what I am looking for, however, I realize now that I should clarify. I want to extract the subjects which the students do as well as the (S) code for each subject and the mark which they got for the subject. I created the columns for this on the far right of the sheet (Cells X to AR). Is it possible to populate those cells with the data?

Comment: Sorry, @player0 my mistake - your answer if perfect and you are a Sheets Genius.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with it being a list in a single cell you can use the following logic:

`=IF(E3<>0,E$1 & ʺ, ʺ,ʺʺ) & IF(F3<>0,F$1 & ʺ, ʺ,ʺʺ) & ʺ...etcʺ`

Just add to it with G,H,etc following the same pattern.

If you want to fill in the table on the back end of your calculation it will take more work.

Comment: I want to fill in the table to the right of my data in cells X to AR.